# Extract number from string within li with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, string, extract

How do I extract the number part only after the span element ?

```
<ul class="info">
 <li class="name"><span class="textLabel">Name: </span>further (22)</li>
 <li>more stuff</li>
 <li>more stuff</li>
</ul>
```

I can get full text of the `<li>` by using `.contents()`, but since I dont need the span value do I simply use `.contents()[1]` and then get `further (22)`. Its here I have problems - I keep getting errors when using `.match(/\((\d+)\)/` like `TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'match'`.

Comment: I did try `.text()`, but must have messed something else up too because it didnt work earlier - works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*stuff you do to get your element*/.text().match(/\((\d+)\)/);
```

[Contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) returns elements, text nodes and comment nodes. Since you only want the text content, you should use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKR6D/6/) that does exactly that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(parseInt($('li.name').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my_str = mystr.slice(-3,-2);
```

For fixed length only. Or:

```
var my_array=my_input.split("(");
var my_out = my_array[1].slice(1,-1); //Trim final character
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('li').text().match(...)
```

The error is from the fact that you're trying to execute a regex against a DOM node, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vMTtn/)**

```
alert($('.name').text().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]); // 22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = $('li.name').text().split('(')[1].split(')')[0];
```